# How to add values from a form to a table?

Tags: javascript

I need to add the given values from a form  into a table  , how to achieve this using java script  .

i have included the code .  so far what i have done .

Here i created a form and two command buttons to add and delete a row ,

Now all i need is the values that i enter in the form i created should reflect on the table which i created .

Kindly help me out to achieve this  .

```
    <script language="javascript">
    function deleteRow(i)
    {
    document.getElementById('table1').deleteRow(i)
    }
    function addRow()
    {
    var tbody = document.getElementById("table1").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
    var row = document.createElement("TR");
    var cell1 = document.createElement("TD");
    var inp1 =  document.createElement("INPUT");
    inp1.setAttribute("type","text");
    inp1.setAttribute("value","");
    cell1.appendChild(inp1);
    var cell2 = document.createElement("TD");
    var inp2 =  document.createElement("INPUT");
    inp2.setAttribute("type","text");
    inp2.setAttribute("value","");
    cell2.appendChild(inp2);
    var cell3 = document.createElement("TD");
    var inp3 =  document.createElement("INPUT");
    inp3.setAttribute("type","text");
    inp3.setAttribute("value","");
    cell3.appendChild(inp3);
    var cell4 = document.createElement("TD");
    var inp4 =  document.createElement("INPUT");
    inp4.setAttribute("type","button");
    inp4.setAttribute("value","Delete");
    inp4.setAttribute("onClick", "deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowindex)");
    cell4.appendChild(inp4);

    row.appendChild(cell1);
    row.appendChild(cell2);
    row.appendChild(cell3);
    row.appendChild(cell4);
    tbody.appendChild(row);

   //alert(row.innerHTML);
    }
    </script>

    <tr>
    <td>
    F.Name : &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" id="fname"></td>
    </tr>
    <br> <br>
    <tr>


    <td>
    L.Name : &nbsp;
    </td>

    <td><input type="text" value="" id="lname"></td>
    </tr>
    <br> <br>
    <tr>

    <td>
    items  : &nbsp;  &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td width="98"><select name="select" id="item">
        <option value="item1" selected="selected">item1</option>
        <option value="item2">item2</option>
        <option value="item3">item3</option>
        <option value="item4">item4</option>
        <option value="item5">item5</option>

      </select></td>

    </tr>
    <br> <br>
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onClick="addRow();">
    <br> <br>
    <table id="table1">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" value=""></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" width="10"></td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" width="10"></td>

    <td><input type="button" value="Delete"         onclick="deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)">

    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Where problem arises ? You can use `var formCtrl = document.getElementById('fname'); inp1.setAttribute(formCtrl.value);` to set form values inside table's text controls

Answer (score 0):

as you are creating rows manually then why dont you also manage a ID logic that will generate and manage ID's dynamically assigned to the columns then you can fill them easily just you will need to do this then.

```
document.getelementbyID("IDofElement").innerHTML = your content.
```

you will definately need to make use of a logic that will generate and allot ID's to dynamic elemets